# Enocde Char string to Octet string?

Tags: c

How do I encode char string to Octet string in C? For example if have:

```
char *string = "245732473";
```

I need to encode this string to Octet string? How can i do this?

Comment: On many C platforms `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and `string` already is an octet string. What exactly do yo mean?

Comment: This smells like homework ;-)

Comment: what is an octet string?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: An octet is a unit of eight bits, an octet string is a sequence of such units. However, an octet string could be data encoded in many different ways.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: so the interesting question is how to find a platform with `CHAR_BIT` ≠ 8 and how to define an appropriate encoding on that platform.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is, on any modern platform, a string of octets. I noticed that all of your characters are numbers. If you really wanted to convert the numbers represented by the ascii characters there to the numbers you see when you print them out, you should use the atoi function in a for loop.